# Count data from the logs

Tags: awk, grep, pattern-matching

I have a log file with the format as bellow:

```
 1: 2017-01-17 00:00:00,723 - [INFO] gid: 123456787  type: A
 2: 2017-01-17 00:00:00,727 - [INFO] gid: 123456787  Trans: 178
 3: 2017-01-17 00:00:00,729 - [INFO] gid: 123456788  type: B
 4: 2017-01-17 00:00:00,731 - [INFO] gid: 123456788  Trans: 121
 5: 2017-01-17 00:00:00,751 - [INFO] gid: 123456789  type: C
 6: 2017-01-17 00:00:00,771 - [INFO] gid: 123456790  type: D
 7: 2017-01-17 00:00:00,787 - [INFO] gid: 123456790  Trans: 121
 8: 2017-01-17 00:00:00,778 - [INFO] gid: 123456791  type: C
 9: 2017-01-17 00:00:00,789 - [INFO] gid: 123456791  Trans: 150
```

My goal is count total of Trans group by type. My idea is merge every 02 rows and then grep with  keywords of types.

```
$ cat logfile.txt |awk 'ORS=NR%2?FS:RS'|grep A 
2017-01-17 00:00:00,723 - [INFO] gid: 123456787  type: A 2017-01-17 00:00:00,727 - [INFO] gid: 123456787  Total: 178

$cat logfile.txt |awk 'ORS=NR%2?FS:RS'|grep C
2017-01-17 00:00:00,751 - [INFO] gid: 123456789  type: C 2017-01-17 00:00:00,771 - [INFO] gid: 123456790  type: D
```

The expected output:

```
$ cat logfile.txt |awk 'ORS=NR%2?FS:RS'|grep B|awk '{sum+=$16} END {print sum}
121
```

Unfortunately the logs is including the rows of `type` without the next row of `Trans` (row 5).

Any idea to help me to complete my goal.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to do all this `ORS` magic: just store the last *type* that was found and make us of an array to keep track of the values that appeared for each one.

Take advantage of the useful data to be the last word at the end of the lines and extract it with `$NF`:

```
awk '$NF ~ /^[0-9]+$/ {          # if last field is a digit
         data[type]+=$NF; next   # make the addition to this value
     }
     {type=$NF}                  # otherwise, pick the type value

     # finally, loop through the array and print the data
     END {for (i in data)        
          print i, data[i]}' file
```

With your given file:

```
$ awk '$NF ~ /^[0-9]+$/ {data[type]+=$NF; next} {type=$NF} END {for (i in data) print i, data[i]}' f
A 178
B 121
C 150
D 121
```